# C++ application that returns JSON strings on Azure or other cloud providers

Tags: c++, azure, architecture, cloud

I'm currently designing a software that should run on a cloud (Azure, Amazon, Google). The software performs several time- and resource-consuming tasks. Because of this, to reduce costs and leverage some existing software we have, we're considering developing the server side of the application with C++.

So far, our architecture considers writing unmanaged libraries with C API entry points, which in turn uses the C++ code. Then we'll write a C# ASP.NET Core application with WebApi controllers that would simply use P/Invoke to call the unmanaged libraries. The return values are JSON strings. Finally, the client apps are Android and iOS, and a SPA for web access. We're leaning towards Azure with Azure SQL as well, using Web Applications.

However, we are now wondering whether the ASP.NET Core app makes sense at all, since it only passes the control over the unmanaged libraries, which in turn do all the heavy lifting. I'm looking for a way to make Azure Web Application to invoke a C++ program that, in turn, returns a JSON string, depending on parameters. That would save us having to write the ASP.NET Core app.

How could I achieve this with Azure, or with any other cloud provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Azure Functions. You can call Windows native console apps inside your AZ Function and then return it's output.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/

Comment: Yes, this will do. I hope one day there'll be a "web api"-like framework for C++, but Azure Functions covers our needs for now. Thank you!